# How do I use .data in filter_at?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

The following code will filter a table of isotope combinations to identify combinations where only one element is isotopically enriched.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  C12 = rep(c(2:0), 2),
  C13 = rep(c(0:2), 2),
  H1 = rep(c(0, 1), each = 3),
  H2 = rep(c(1, 0), each = 3)
)

element_filter <- "H2"

dplyr::filter_at(df, dplyr::vars(element_filter), dplyr::all_vars(. == 0))
```

I would like to include this code in a package and avoid the `no visible binding for global variable ‘.’` warning. When I change the `filter_at` call to

```
dplyr::filter_at(df, dplyr::vars(element_filter), dplyr::all_vars(.data == 0))
```

I receive the following error, `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. I am successfully using the `.data` pronoun in other functions, but am unable to figure out how to get it working here. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `dplyr::filter_at(df, dplyr::vars(element_filter), dplyr::all_vars(. == 0))` works for me without any warning. `R version 3.5.2`

Comment: Agree that the posted code works, but when trying to change to `dplyr::filter_at(df, dplyr::vars(element_filter), dplyr::all_vars(.data == 0))`, it doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: hmmm..I am not sure but maybe because `all_vars` doesn't expect `.data` argument? `?all_vars` says it wants input as `expr`. Though I maybe wrong here to interpret.

Comment: Your example can be accomplished with just `filter`. Are there cases where the table would have more than two different chemical elements? Also, do you only want cases where there is exactly one element that's isotopically enriched, or no more than one element that's isotopically enriched?

Comment: Yes on both counts. `expression_filter` is determined based on a user-provided molecular formula that can also include N, O, S and their isotopes as well as an argument to indicate which element(s) are label-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While many functions often support both `.` and `.data`, they are not interchangable in general. Specifically, `filter_at` calls an internal function `apply_filter_syms`. That function in turn maps the `.` pronoun to the symbol being looked at, as seen in the following line of [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/af7b78d52fdbf8390e49688b74677b92bb91484b/R/colwise-filter.R#L83):

```
pred <- map(syms, function(sym) expr_substitute(pred, quote(.), sym))
```

Note that there is no mention of `.data` anywhere in that function. Because there is no special treatment of `.data`, it is treated like any other variable. R will traverse the calling stack until it finds the definition of `.data`, which in the dplyr world is a pronoun used to refer to "the current data frame". Your filter predicate is then comparing the entire data frame to 0, not just the columns of interest. This results in the error you're observing.

Rather than trying to get the function working with `.data`, I suggest instead [tackling the original warning instead](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/451).

Comment: I had been wondering if this was the case and did not know how to track down the answer. Thank you! I like the `. <-  "Shut up"` solution I had seen elsewhere...